# How to listen for events on popup window with different protocol (HTTP vs HTTPS)?

Tags: javascript, events, authentication, protocols

I want to be able to securely authenticate users on my site from any non-secure page. So I made a `window.open()` popup to open a secure sign in form. The plan is that after the user signs up or authenticates, the popup would close and the parent window would refresh.

Closing the popup works fine, however, due to Cross Site Scripting rules, when trying to refresh the parent, I get the following:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://localhost/ from frame with URL https://localhost/signin_popup. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.
```

I can't simply subscribe on at the parent to `onunload`, because the authentication popup may traverse through several pages before its ready to refresh the parent. I'm currently trying to see if I can bind custom events to the popup window object from the parent, and fire them from within the popup, but to no avail.

So...

How can I make a popup window interact with a parent window, or have the parent window subscribe to custom events of the popup window when protocols do not match?

Comment: You can't. That's a security restriction to prevent insecure or unknown websites from harvesting sensitive information through javascript injections. The type of behavior you're wanting to do is the exact behavior a black hat would use maliciously to collect information if it was possible.

Comment: @JoelEtherton I could see that pertaining to sending data, but why not be able to listen for event firings?

Comment: Could you just redirect your anonymous web requests to https from the beginning?  So that when your popup is fired the parent window will be https as well.

Comment: @Miguel-F Would love to, unfortunately, our site doesn't benchmark well when running on HTTPS all the time

Comment: `https` and `http` are completely different origins in the eyes of [`same-origin policy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: @Esailija under that note, though, wouldn't I be able to add each "domain" to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`? I'm not sure this falls entirely under the same security policy. I think it's part of it, but not all of it.

Comment: Once the users are logged in they will continue communicating over SSL. Is that correct?  If so, then why bother with a popup window and not just direct them to the https page to login?

Comment: @KyleMacey According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control), CORS only applies to XHR, canvas drawImage, Web fonts and webgl textures. Not sure if you can use the postMessage api though ... sec

Comment: @KyleMacey: Event firings *are* the sending of data. It's all data. You should not even be able to access objects or methods within a page from a script lying in an alternate domain or protocol.

Comment: Got it guys. Looks like I'll be taking a different approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to implement cross-origin window communication with the [`postMessage`-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage)

To post a message to the other window:

```
otherWindowRef.postMessage( 'message', origin );
```

You will then receive it on the other window:

```
window.addEventListener( "message", function() {
   //message was received 
}, false );
```

The other window will likewise `.postMessage` back to the main window and the main window gets a message event.

Comment: Thanks, I probably can't actually implement this, because a vast majority of our users are not using HTML5 compliant browsers, but it was definitely good to learn!

Comment: Also seems like it'd be a proper answer for future SO users, so most likely will accept answer